# Compiled with warnings. /home/hadrnet/Desktop/app/frontend/node_modules/react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc

i bulid app of videos stream 
try to run my react native with webrtc 

i get this error

i get this error

i get this error
Compiled with warnings. 
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/myapp/frontend/node_modules/react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js

thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
../../../../../../../../Desktop/school/frontend/node_modules/react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js
node_modules/react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js:59

  56 |   },
  57 | };
  58 | 
> 59 | const View = requireNativeComponent('RTCVideoView', RTCView, {nativeOnly: {
  60 |   testID: true,
  61 |   accessibilityComponentType: true,
  62 |   renderToHardwareTextureAndroid: true,

__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:100

   97 |         );
   98 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
   99 |     }
> 100 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  101 | };
  102 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  103 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:100

   97 |         );
   98 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
   99 |     }
> 100 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  101 | };
  102 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  103 |     return {

../../../../../../../../Desktop/school/frontend/screens/chat/VideoScreen.js
http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:142474:97
__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:100

   97 |         );
   98 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
   99 |     }
> 100 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  101 | };
  102 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  103 |     return {

../../../../../../../../Desktop/school/frontend/App.js
http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:897:103
__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:100

   97 |         );
   98 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
   99 |     }
> 100 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  101 | };
  102 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  103 |     return {

../../../../../../../../Desktop/school/frontend/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js
node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:1
__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:100

   97 |         );
   98 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
   99 |     }
> 100 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  101 | };
  102 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  103 |     return {

1
http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:153966:18
__webpack_require__
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:789

  786 | };
  787 | 
  788 | // Execute the module function
> 789 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  790 | 
  791 | // Flag the module as loaded
  792 | module.l = true;

(anonymous function)
/home/hadrnet/Desktop/school/frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | 
  855 | // Load entry module and return exports
> 856 | return hotCreateRequire(1)(__webpack_require__.s = 1);
      | ^  857 | 

(anonymous function)
http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:860:10
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u
thank u